# Error while using Flutter in the iOS Razorpay integration

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode

Failed to build module 'Razorpay'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.6.1 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.66 clang-1316.0.20.12)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.

Razorpay integration in ios.

Comment: You need to upgrade your Xcode